# What we can say about block inverse besides the Schur complement?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, schur-complement

Suppose I have a matrix $M$, which has a block structure $%
\begin{bmatrix}
A & B \\ 
B^{T} & C%
\end{bmatrix}%
$, where A has the inverse. How can I better numerically calculate $A^{-1}B$ ?  I
saw somewhere that I may first do cholesky factorization, say $RR^{\ast }=$ $M$. Then write R also as block structure $%
\begin{bmatrix}
R_{1} & R_{2} \\ 
0 & R_{4}%
\end{bmatrix}%
,$ 
 then $A^{-1}B$ would equal to $R_{1}^{-1}R_{2}$.

Is that true?  I tried with schur complement, but it doesn't seem a proper
tool to answer that.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SoManyProb_for_a_brol Why do you think that the Schur complement and block inverse formula will help you in calculating $A^{-1}B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably $M$ is real and positive definite. Then what you read is mostly true, except that the Cholesky decomposition should be $M=R^T R$. You may verify that
$$
\pmatrix{A&B\\ B^T&C}
=\pmatrix{R_1^T&0\\ R_2^T&R_4^T}
\pmatrix{R_1&R_2\\ 0&R_4}
=\pmatrix{R_1^T R_1&R_1^T R_2\\ R_2^T R_1&R_2^T R_2 + R_1^T R_4}.
$$
Therfore $A^{-1}B=(R_1^TR_1)^{-1}(R_1^TR_2)=R_1^{-1}R_2$.

However, if all you need is $A^{-1}B$, I think it's more efficient to decompose $A$ as $LL^T$ and solve $LL^TX=B$, rather than decomposing $M$ and solve $R_1X=R_2$. But both ways for finding $A^{-1}B$ are backward stable, anyway.